# Kotlin multi-platform multi-project how to get individual project to build

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, gradle-multi-project-build

I have been spinning wheels for hours trying to get a Kotlin Multi Platform project to build within a Gradle Multi Project sample.

The sample project that I have has the following structure

Where 'myKotlinMPLib' has dependency on class within 'myDependencyLib'

```
mac> tree.without.build
.
├── README.md
├── git.push.sh
└── simplified_top_level_project
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    ├── buildSrc
    │   ├── build.gradle.kts
    │   └── settings.gradle.kts
    ├── gradle
    │   └── wrapper
    │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
    │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
    ├── gradlew
    ├── gradlew.bat
    ├── myDependencyLib
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── build.gradle.kts
    │   ├── coverage.sh
    │   ├── gradle
    │   │   └── wrapper
    │   │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
    │   ├── gradle.properties
    │   ├── releaseToLocal.sh
    │   ├── settings.gradle.kts
    │   └── src
    │       ├── commonMain
    │       │   └── kotlin
    │       │       └── com
    │       │           └── asgard
    │       │               └── DependencyInterface.kt
    │       ├── jvmMain
    │       │   └── kotlin
    │       │       └── asgard
    │       │           └── DependencyImplementation.kt
    │       └── jvmTest
    │           └── kotlin
    │               └── com
    │                   └── asgard
    │                       └── TestFromDependency.kt
    ├── myKotlinMPLib
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── build.gradle.kts
    │   ├── coverage.sh
    │   ├── gradle
    │   │   └── wrapper
    │   │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
    │   ├── gradle.properties
    │   ├── releaseToLocal.sh
    │   ├── settings.gradle.kts
    │   └── src
    │       ├── jvmMain
    │       │   └── kotlin
    │       │       └── asgard
    │       │           └── ConsumerImplementationDependency.kt
    │       └── jvmTest
    │           └── kotlin
    │               └── com
    │                   └── asgard
    │                       └── ConsumerTest.kt
    └── settings.gradle.kts
```

within 'simplified_top_level_project' I am able to run 'gradle build'

```
mac> pwd && gradle build
/Users/nickolaykondratyev/git_repos/glassthought-sandbox/simplified_top_level_project
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
37 actionable tasks: 37 up-to-date
```

However, when I try to run `gradle build` within 'myKotlinMPLib' I get an error

```
mac> cd myKotlinMPLib/
mac> gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/nickolaykondratyev/git_repos/glassthought-sandbox/simplified_top_level_project/myKotlinMPLib/build.gradle.kts' line: 38

* What went wrong:
Project with path ':myDependencyLib' could not be found in root project 'myKotlinMPLib'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 362ms
```

To replicate locally can run the project using

```bash
git clone https://github.com/nickolay-kondratyev/glassthought-sandbox.git \
&& cd glassthought-sandbox \
&& git checkout stack-overflow-question-3 \
&& cd simplified_top_level_project \
&& echo "------------------------------------------------------" \
&& echo "At simplified_top_level_project 'gradle build' works:" \
&& gradle build \
&& echo "------------------------------------------------------" \
&& echo "However, when navigating to 'myKotlinMPLib', build does not work" \
&& cd myKotlinMPLib \
&& gradle build
```

Or without running full code of sample project can be found here: https://github.com/nickolay-kondratyev/glassthought-sandbox/tree/stack-overflow-question-3

Gradle thinks 'myKotlinMPLib' is a root project. How can I get individual projects to build in command line while they have dependency on libraries that are nearby and are under top level root project?

Comment: Actually, maybe `gradle :myKotlinMPLib:build` from root is all I need for now.